# Maximum possible average of an array sub sequence -- Need efficient solution

Tags: java, algorithm

Input

```
1: array size (1 to 10^5)
2: Number to take average (1 to 10^3)
3: elements in array (1 to 10^5) Non sorted, any order is possible
```

Output: Maximum possible average of any sub-array.

```
Eg:
5 3
1 2 3 4 5
o/p = 5

5 4
1 2 3 4 5
o/p = 3

for first example seq will be sum[0,4]=15 and its average with 3 will be 5.
for second example seq will be sum[2,4]=12 and its average with 4 will be 3.
```

I already have below given solution of o(n^2) but its not working for large inputs.

```
            long max = 0;
            for( int m = 0; m < people; m++ )
            {
                long sum = 0;
                for( int n = m; n < people; n++ )
                {
                    sum = sum + chocolateArray[n];
                    if( sum % boxes == 0 )
                    {
                        if( ( sum / boxes ) > max )
                        {
                            max = sum / boxes;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println( max );
```

where `people` is array size, `boxes` is average number and `chocolateArray` is original array.

Please provide efficient solution. I thought to take it through `dynamic programming` but creating two dimensional array of 10^5 size is causing outofmemory issue.

Comment: In ur second case, why did you take just the [2,4] and not [0,4]?

Comment: You need to clarify the task. I guess you are looking for the subarray which sum is divisible by the number of boxes, and you want the maximum of those? It is very similar to maximum subarray sum problem, with extra constraints on divisibility.

Comment: @justhalf yes, you can tell similar but I know that we can solve in o(n) and that is applicable when we have negative numbers in array otherwise sum will be max till last every-time. Here we are having all +ve nums.

Comment: @ShanuGupta because in second case sum of [0,4] = 15 which is not divisible by 4. And we can not get average by this sum.

Comment: hmm this clarified, I'm thinking of modified kadanes algorithm.

Comment: The problem can be reduced to finding minimum prefix sum or suffix sum or combination of both that gives the correct residue. The tricky part would be the combination.

Comment: @justhalf yes, I am just trying to fit dynamic programming to reuse already calculated steps. But my solution is causing outofmemory.

Comment: @justhalf and one more thing array is non sorted. I forgot to mention this in my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since all numbers are positive, the only effective constraint is the divisibility. So the question is asking for the maximum subarray sum that is divisible by `m`, the number of boxes.

This can be done by creating an array of the cumulative sum, modulo `m`, then finding two places with the same numbers, as far apart as possible. Since there are at most `m` values, we can simply store the minimum and maximum index of every possible residue, then take the one with the maximum subarray sum. The code below does that.

```
cumsum = int[people+1];
minPos = int[boxes];
maxPos = int[boxes];
Arrays.fill(minPos, -1);
Arrays.fill(maxPos, -1);
int residue = 0;
for(int i=0; i<people; i++){
    cumsum[i+1] = cumsum[i] + chocolateArray[i]; // For simplicity the array length is 1 longer
    residue = cumsum[i+1] % boxes;
    if(minPos[residue] == -1) minPos[residue] = i;
    maxPos[residue] = i;
}
int max = 0;
for(int i=0; i<boxes; i++){
    int sum = cumsum[maxPos[i]+1] - cumsum[minPos[i]+1];
    if(sum > max){
        max = sum;
    }
}
System.out.println(max/boxes);
```

For example:

```
People = 5
Boxes = 4
Array = [1, 2, 3,  4,  5]
Cumulative = [1, 3, 6, 10, 15]
Residue = [1, 3, 2, 2, 3]
MinMaxPos[0] = (-1, -1) -> sum = 0 -> avg = 0
MinMaxPos[1] = (0, 0) -> sum = 0 -> avg = 0
MinMaxPos[2] = (2, 3) -> sum = 4 -> avg = 1
MinMaxPos[3] = (1, 4) -> sum = 12 -> avg = 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Building on @justhalf's brilliant solution. we will be able to do this using a single pass and only a single array

let `dp[boxes]` be a array of length `boxes` where `dp[i]` will hold the minimum sum so far which has `i = current_sum % boxes`

Since all the numbers are positive number we can store *only* the first occurrence of a the particular `residue` since the next time this residue occurs it will be greater that the previous sum.

At each iteration we check if a particular `residue` has been already found. If yes then then we subtract the `current_sum` with the previous sum of that residue.

Else we update the sum for the residue and move.

```
int maxSubArrayAverage(vector<int> people, int boxes)
{
    vector<int> dp(boxes, -1);
    int max_sum = 0, current_sum = 0;
    dp[0] = 0; // if residue is 0 entire current_sum is the choice
    for(int i=0; i < people.size(); ++i)
    {
        current_sum += people[i];
        int residue = current_sum % boxes;

        if(dp[residue] == -1) // update for the first time
        {
            dp[residue] = current_sum;
        }
        else
        {
            max_sum= max(max_sum, current_sum - dp[residue]);
            // cout << i << ' ' << current_sum << ' ' << residue << ' ' << max_average << endl;
        }
    }
    // copy(dp.begin(), dp.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
    // cout << endl;
    return max_sum/boxes;
}
```

Comment: Yes, we can calculate max average in one go. Don't need to retain maxPos.  Good One!!

Comment: Yep, definitely we can do this. I put the min and max pos for clarity. +1